# idea cannot find class to import

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I opened `gradle` project in `idea` using `File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources -> Create project from existing sources`. (Due to certain circumstances I am unable to import it as `gradle` project).

The project is a `gradle` plugin. `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: "kotlin"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group = 'com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile gradleApi()
}
```

But in the class it marks classes with red as it is unable to find it.

[image]

But I am able to run `gradle build` successfully. What is the problem?

Comment: How do you expect the gradle API to appear as a dependency in your project if you don't use the gradle import?

Comment: Hm...So as long as I do not import it as gradle project it won't work? Well dead end then.

Comment: Well, you can always add JAR files from your local gradle installation to make it compile.

Comment: @IngoKegel it compiles fine. It is just IDE is unable to find dependencies.

Comment: Surely it only compiles with gradle, not in IJ.